# They said it is a ginseng but I'm not sure what plant is this?

Tags: identification

They said to me it is a ginseng but I doubt it.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not ginseng. Rather it is Buddha Belly (*[Jatropha podagrica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jatropha_podagrica)*). Note that they are easily confused since they both have flowers in umbels and grow from a swollen root, but if you compare the leaves of each you see that ginseng has short stalks on the leaflets, where this one has a stalk into the main leaf, no leaflets - in botanical terms it is more peltate.

Comment: Thank you for that. I am so surprised to know that it is a poisonous plant because we are mixing it to a Chinese wine and drink it. We thought it is a ginseng.

Comment: What is the use of Buddha Belly?